# how to make sms sent with adb show in messages app

Tags: android, adb, android-shell

I'm using a Samsung phone with Android 10
I found this adb command online

```
adb shell service call isms 7 i32 0 s16 "com.android.mms.service" s16 "${phone}" s16 "null" s16 "'${text}'" s16 "null" s16 "null"
```

This works, it sends the SMS if i respect the character limit. However, the SMS does not show up in the phone's messages app

I can't find documentation about all those flags and what they mean. Please help me and tell me how I can make it show in the messages app. If this is not possible with adb, is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by providing another argument at the end

```
i32 1
```

[this article](https://oofnivek.medium.com/android-send-sms-with-adb-5f16d7d9d4f8) helped me

Based on [this documentation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/android10-d4-s1-release/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/ISms.aidl) it seems i needed to provide the **persistMessageForNonDefaultSmsApp** boolean

Not sure if this was the way to go, I'm not an android dev, but it works :/